# Why do I have to keep refreshing the page for the output of the code to change and actually follow what I intended it to do?

Tags: javascript, html, conditional-statements

Apparently I posted a question  couple of minutes ago saying that my code was not working because the output was always the same and didnt change even when I put different inputs, but I deleted it because I found out that the problem was that I had to refresh the whole page and answer again to get the intended output. I have to keep doing this everytime I wanted that or else the output would stay the same. Could someone help me figure out why that happens and how to fix it?

**The Code:**

```js
var q1Agree = document.getElementById("q1-agree");
var q1Neutral = document.getElementById("q1-nuetral");
var q1Disagree = document.getElementById("q1-disagree");

var q2Agree = document.getElementById("q2-agree");
var q2Neutral = document.getElementById("q2-nuetral");
var q2Disagree = document.getElementById("q2-disagree");
var result = document.getElementById("result");

var pnum = 0;

function personalitycondition() {
  if (q1Agree.checked) {
    pnum += 2;
  } else if (q1Neutral.checked) {
    pnum += 1;
  } else if (q1Disagree.checked) {
    pnum += 0;
  }

  if (q2Agree.checked) {
    pnum += 2;
  } else if (q2Neutral.checked) {
    pnum += 1;
  } else if (q2Disagree.checked) {
    pnum += 0;
  }

  if (pnum > 4) {
    result.innerHTML = "You are a confident and energetic person.";
  } else if (pnum >= 2) {
    result.innerHTML = "You are a balanced and level-headed person.";
  } else {
    result.innerHTML = "You are a reserved and thoughtful person.";
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <form id="q1">
    <h3>You are open about your feelings</h3>
    <label for="agree">Agree</label>
    <input type="radio" id="q1-agree" name="q1-personality" value="Agree"><br><br>
    <label for="nuetral">Nuetral</label>
    <input type="radio" id="q1-nuetral" name="q1-personality" value="Nuetral"><br><br>
    <label for="disagree">Disagree</label>
    <input type="radio" id="q1-disagree" name="q1-personality" value="Disagree"><br><br>
  </form>
  <form id="q2">
    <h3>It is difficult to get you excited</h3>
    <label for="agree">Agree</label>
    <input type="radio" id="q2-agree" name="q2-personality" value="Agree"><br><br>
    <label for="nuetral">Nuetral</label>
    <input type="radio" id="q2-nuetral" name="q2-personality" value="Nuetral"><br><br>
    <label for="disagree">Disagree</label>
    <input type="radio" id="q2-disagree" name="q2-personality" value="Disagree"><br><br>
  </form>

  <button type="button" onclick="personalitycondition()">Find Your Personality</button>
  <p id="result"></p>

</body>

</html>
```

Plus, I didnt really try anything because I dont know if the problem is related to the code or something outside

Comment: Move `var pnum = 0;` inside the function. Otherwise, it doesn't reset to 0 when you click the button a second time.

Answer (score 0):

In short, the issue is in the JavaScript you've provided. You have defined the `pnum` variable globally. This means that after the function `personalitycondition` completes, the `pnum` function keeps its value, and the starting value of `pnum` the next time the function executes is not 0 anymore, but instead is what the function left behind itself.

A simple solution would be to put the `pnum` variable inside the function, so that the variable is reset every time we execute the `personalitycondition` function. Another solution would be to set `pnum` to 0 in the start of the function.